# maven-cucumber-reporting plugin is not generating the report - in latest 5.3.0 version

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, reporting, cucumber-java

After copy pasting the code from github for maven cucumber reporting, the report is not generated in the target folder. I'm not sure what went missing. I tried with running with Runner class and MVN console both result did not generate the report in the target folder

POM file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MavenWeb</groupId>
    <artifactId>Coderio_Demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Coderio_Demo</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.monochromata.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>reporting-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.56</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                    <version>5.3.0</version>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>execution</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <projectName>cucumber-jvm-example</projectName>
                                <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass generation 
                                    of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                                <skip>false</skip>
                                <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                                <outputDirectory>target/customizereports/</outputDirectory>
                                <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                                <inputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json</inputDirectory>
                                <jsonFiles>
                                    <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                    <param>**/*.json</param>
                                </jsonFiles>
                                <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                                <classificationDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classifications</classificationDirectory>
                                <classificationFiles>
                                    <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                    <param>sample.properties</param>
                                    <param>other.properties</param>
                                </classificationFiles>
                                <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                                <!-- optional, set true to group features by its Ids -->
                                <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
                                <!-- optional, set true to get a final report with latest results 
                                    of the same test from different test runs -->
                                <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                                <!-- optional, set true to fail build on test failures -->
                                <checkBuildResult>true</checkBuildResult>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>


                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this my runnerfile

```
package testRunner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

//import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
//import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/Features/", plugin = { "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json",
        "pretty", "html:target/html-report/cucumber-html-reports.html",
        "junit:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.xml" }, glue = {
                "StepDefination" }, tags = "@LogOut1wwww1", monochrome = true)
public class TestRunner {


}
```

I ran through `mvn clean verify`

test case got executed, but reports were not generated

Answer (score 1):

Change your build section in pom.xml to this

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/cucumber-reports</outputDirectory>
              <jsonFiles>
                <jsonFile>**/*.json</jsonFile>
              </jsonFiles>
              <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>true</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
              <mergeFeaturesById>true</mergeFeaturesById>
              <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
              <skipEmptyJSONFiles>true</skipEmptyJSONFiles>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: yeah i tried , but still no luck , with same POM and runner file and did changes as you mentioned ,still no folder is generated in target folder @Motivated Mind

Comment: I use it this way and works perfectly for me
```
<execution>
 <id>report</id>
 <phase>integration-test</phase>
 <goals>
   <goal>generate</goal>
 </goals>
 <configuration>
   <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
   <jsonFiles>
  <jsonFile>**/cucumber/*.json</jsonFile>
   </jsonFiles>
   <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>true</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
   <mergeFeaturesById>true</mergeFeaturesById>
   <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
   <skipEmptyJSONFiles>true</skipEmptyJSONFiles>
 </configuration>
  </execution>
```
You see any error / message?

Comment: Below the updated POM as you mentioned but no report has been generated in target folder ```<executions><execution><id>report</id><phase>integration-test</phase><goals><goal>generate</goal></goals><configuration><outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/newReports/</outputDirectory>
<jsonFiles><jsonFile>**/cucumber/*.json</jsonFile></jsonFiles>
<mergeFeaturesWithRetest>true</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
<mergeFeaturesById>true</mergeFeaturesById><checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult><skipEmptyJSONFiles>true</skipEmptyJSONFiles></configuration></execution></executions>```

Comment: you check my repo fro more information and kindly let me know what changes i have to make it here

https://github.com/zulfikarayub/CodeRio_Demo

Comment: I have fixed the issue and raised PR. Have a look. The problem is that you had wrapped plugin under `<pluginManagement></pluginManagement>`. This is to good for a multimodule maven project unlike your case.

Comment: perfect thanks for the help , it working as expected , as of now i ma getting result through MVN clean verify , can i get same from test runner also is it possible